# Macro do loop without any output

Tags: loops, macros, sas

My purpose is to find out whether there is a follow up. Firstly, objid needs to compare with all `R1` to `R14`. If objid equals some `RX`, then have a check whether there is a follow up in `R(X+1)`. In total, the maximum `R` is 14. If `objid=R14`, there is no follow-up. For example, objid in the first record is 1111. It is the same as R1 and there is a follow up `R2` as `R2` is not missing. The second record `R1=R14` but no follow-up.

I have written a code, but no output. Don't understand where the problem is.

Data looks like:

```
objid  R1    R2    ...   R14
-----  ----  ----        ----
1111   1111  1112  ...  
2222   1101  2201  ...   2222
...             
4567   5234  4567  ...
```

Codes:

```
%macro rr(n=);
   data linkrr;
      set linkrev_tricup;
      %do i=1 %to &n;
         %if %eval(r&i.=objid) %then %do;
            %let j=%eval(&i.+1);
            %if %eval(r&j.>0) %then %eval(index_rr=1); 
            %else %eval(index_rr=0);
            output;
         %end;
      %end;
   run;
%mend rr;
%rr(n=14);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing macro and datastep functions. Macro functions are just code generators. They can not evaluate information that is passed in the datastep.
Try using only datastep code with an array for this
e.g.

```
data linkrev_tricup;
   infile datalines ; 
   input objid R1 R2 R14;
   datalines;                      
1111    1111    1112   .
2222    1101    2201   2222
;

data linkrr;
set linkrev_tricup;
index_rr=0;
array R [*] R1 -- R14;
do i = 1 to dim(R)-1;
    if R[i] eq objid and R[i+1] gt 0 then do; 
        index_rr=1; 
        leave;
    end;
end;
if R[dim(R)] eq objid then index_rr=1; 
run;
```

Comment: Array approach makes sense, but as I read OP she wants she wants index_rr=0 for the second record, so I would remove you last IF statement.

Comment: I did not really understand that part of the question. In that case just leave out the `if R[dim(R)] eq objid then index_rr=1;` part.